# What exactly does the 'boxcox' function in R do?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, linear-model

I am familiar with the power transform family and I know how to estimate the MLE for $\lambda$ for given samples of a random variable. I have been using the 'boxcox' function in R for a sample of a random variable that depends linearly on a latent variable (i.e. a linear model) and it works very well. The problem is that I don't quite know how it works on such linear models.

The [official reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/boxcox.html) won't give clear clues on how to answer my question. Can you provide some information on the answer to my question?

Comment: Besides Jeromy's nice answer, you might find a few additional details in the book that MASS is the package for (*[Modern Applied Statistics with S](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/MASS4/)*, Venables and Ripley). If I was close to my copy, I'd check it now.

Comment: Thanks Glen_b! The book gave me a clear idea of what the function does.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but the real official reference is arguably "the code". In this case it's a little harder to find (it's a method, and it's hidden behind a namespace), but this command shows the code for the default method.

```
library('MASS')
getAnywhere('boxcox.default')
```

The result is the following (see also `getAnywhere('boxcox.lm')`):

```
A single object matching ‘boxcox.default’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for boxcox from namespace MASS
  namespace:MASS
with value

function (object, lambda = seq(-2, 2, 1/10), plotit = TRUE, interp = (plotit && 
    (m < 100)), eps = 1/50, xlab = expression(lambda), ylab = "log-Likelihood", 
    ...) 
{
    if (is.null(y <- object$y) || is.null(xqr <- object$qr)) 
        stop(gettextf("%s does not have both 'qr' and 'y' components", 
            sQuote(deparse(substitute(object)))), domain = NA)
    if (any(y <= 0)) 
        stop("response variable must be positive")
    n <- length(y)
    y <- y/exp(mean(log(y)))
    logy <- log(y)
    xl <- loglik <- as.vector(lambda)
    m <- length(xl)
    for (i in 1L:m) {
        if (abs(la <- xl[i]) > eps) 
            yt <- (y^la - 1)/la
        else yt <- logy * (1 + (la * logy)/2 * (1 + (la * logy)/3 * 
            (1 + (la * logy)/4)))
        loglik[i] <- -n/2 * log(sum(qr.resid(xqr, yt)^2))
    }
    if (interp) {
        sp <- spline(xl, loglik, n = 100)
        xl <- sp$x
            loglik <- sp$y
        m <- length(xl)
    }
    if (plotit) {
        mx <- (1L:m)[loglik == max(loglik)][1L]
        Lmax <- loglik[mx]
        lim <- Lmax - qchisq(19/20, 1)/2
        dev.hold()
        on.exit(dev.flush())
        plot(xl, loglik, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, type = "l", 
            ylim = range(loglik, lim))
        plims <- par("usr")
        abline(h = lim, lty = 3)
        y0 <- plims[3L]
        scal <- (1/10 * (plims[4L] - y0))/par("pin")[2L]
        scx <- (1/10 * (plims[2L] - plims[1L]))/par("pin")[1L]
        text(xl[1L] + scx, lim + scal, " 95%", xpd = TRUE)
        la <- xl[mx]
        if (mx > 1 && mx < m) 
            segments(la, y0, la, Lmax, lty = 3)
        ind <- range((1L:m)[loglik > lim])
        if (loglik[1L] < lim) {
            i <- ind[1L]
            x <- xl[i - 1] + ((lim - loglik[i - 1]) * (xl[i] - 
                xl[i - 1]))/(loglik[i] - loglik[i - 1])
            segments(x, y0, x, lim, lty = 3)
        }
        if (loglik[m] < lim) {
            i <- ind[2L] + 1
            x <- xl[i - 1] + ((lim - loglik[i - 1]) * (xl[i] - 
                xl[i - 1]))/(loglik[i] - loglik[i - 1])
            segments(x, y0, x, lim, lty = 3)
        }
    }
    list(x = xl, y = loglik)
}
<bytecode: 0x7ff6e0973120>
<environment: namespace:MASS>
```